# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (target_link_libraries) when adding logs

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I have an ndk project with a CMakeLists.txt that looks like so

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror")

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        main

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        main.c)

target_link_libraries(
        android
        log
)
```

it follows the pattern laid out in all of the NDK example projects listed on the googlesamples github repo. I keep getting `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (target_link_libraries)`, and it seems like most people are solving it with this line

```
add_library(debug <files Name>)
```

but no one is adding that for logging. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, add the **error message** itself into the question post. Phrase "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt (target_link_libraries)" helps only in the error location, but not in the error reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add below to your `CMakeLists.txt` above the line of `target_link_libraries`.

```
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )
```

Then modify `target_link_libraries` as below for linking android **log** lib

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   main

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: I am not sure where this is officially documented. But when you follow the Android Studio project creation wizard (with native support), you will get this similar `CMakeLists.txt` automatically.

Comment: It's in the samples. It should also be in the CMake documentation (I don't think that style of linking libraries is Android specific).

Comment: I am getting 

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
log-lib

Answer (score -1):

**1)** in your code source folder, look for something like "Android.mk" or "project.mk", then remember the path of it.

**2)** go to android studio and click File ==> link c++ project with gradle ==> choose build system ndk-build , then look for the .mk file you found first.
click ok , and sync project.

Comment: this was built with cmake, not ndk-bundle

Comment: @Rafa, Both of them works Cmake or ndk, whatever you find in your code , use it

Comment: neither exist in the project. Just CMakeLists.txt

Comment: then choose the Cmake and click ok syn